# How to expose host machine aliases to Docker container?

Tags: docker

Docker has great documentation on [linking containers](https://docs.docker.com/v1.8/userguide/dockerlinks/) - allowing one container to make use of the other container's environment variables.

However, how would one go about exposing command line aliases (and their respective programs) of the host machine to the Docker container?

Or, perhaps the better way to go about this is to simply configure the Docker container to build from an image that has these aliases / "dotfiles" built in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that you approach to docker as you should. A docker container's purpose is to run a network application and expose it to outside world.
If you need aliases for your application running inside a container, then you have to build an image first, that contains the whole environment your app needs...

Or specify them in the Dockerfile, while building your image.

Comment: Docker is very flexible. It's purpose is whatever you choose its purpose to be. One use is to launch a server to test against using tools in your host (for example, debugging a client in the IDE). In that scenario, it would be very useful if the host could DNS-lookup by docker alias.